# Why don't fingerprint authentication systems don't store 'hashes'?

Tags: authentication, fingerprint

Usual password authentication systems do not store passwords directly on the server, but only hashes of those passwords.
Why do fingerprint authentication systems not offer this possibility?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is iPhone's fingerprint signature a one-way hash?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/43587/is-iphones-fingerprint-signature-a-one-way-hash), [Is there any way to cryptographically hash a human thumbprint?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/42384/is-there-any-way-to-)cryptographically-hash-a-human-thumbprint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Password authentication systems check for full equality. If you make a typo in your password, you will not be authenticated*.

You **cannot** check a fingerprint for full equality; it's a 'scan' and there will always be some minor differences: perhaps you have a small cut in your finger, or you put your finger slightly rotated on the device and the digitalization process displaces a few pixels.

A hash is designed to implement the [avalanche effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalanche_effect); a small change in the input causes a large difference in the output. That means that two slightly different passwords or two slightly different fingerprints produce two completely different hashes. If you have the hash of a fingerprint, there's no way of verifying whether it matches a slightly different fingerprint.

*<sub>: such a verification system would work by verifying the hash with not only the hash of the actually entered password, but also the hash of *all possible typos*.</sub>

Comment: I believe Facebook implements an authentication system similar to what you described about typos.