# Why does Windows facial recognition not require a password on startup?

Tags: authentication, windows, fingerprint, facial-recognition

I was reading the following question:

[Why do mobile devices force user to type password after reboot?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/134392/why-do-mobile-devices-force-user-to-type-password-after-reboot)

To find out why fingerprint authentication on my Windows 10 laptop isn't an option on startup. It turned out to be because it did not meet the following requirements:

> - On each entry, the device must transform the password through a key-derivation function into the one and only correct encryption key, otherwise the device won't be able to decrypt the data
> - Derived through a one-way function, not "unlocked" by comparing data provided by a user with a pattern stored on the device

Then how come a Windows device can be unlocked on initial startup with facial recognition? That doesn't fulfill the two requirements above.

Comment: Password == Symmetric-key.
Windows Hello + PIN == User provided entropy.

[This video is very informative.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cC24rPBvdhA)